# xamarin pre-built CRM with Couchbase Lite

Tags: xamarin, couchbase, couchbase-lite

[See here a schema of my setup !!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U22xA.png)

I want to use the pre-built Xamarin App: XamarinCRM from https://www.xamarin.com/prebuilt

But I want to remove the Azure services and change it with Couchbase Lite. Therefore I installed the package for Couchbase Lite in the 2 mobile projects. Then I created a Shared Project with all the DB code like CRUD operations.

In the PCL XamarinCRM, which calls originally the webservices, I want to replace these calls with CRUD code from the newly created Shared Project.

I always get the error: Type or namespace name 'Couchbase' could not be found. Probably this is because when compiling the XamarinCRM (PCL) it includes the shared project but of course the PCL doesn't know this package.

Above, there's the link showing a schema of the setup.

Anyone an idea of how to solve this?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40449941/4984832

Comment: do you mean using dependency injection? I created the interface in the PCL and created an implementation in the Shared Project + PCL. However in the PCL I cannot instantiate it with the impl. of the Shared Project since it's not known there. Any help?

Comment: Via dependency injection (IoC), Forms' `DependencyService`, etc... you would be calling the Couchbase APIs within your `XamarinCRM.iOS` or `XamarinCRM.Android` projects.